# Making div hide on click outside it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hide

my question is, how can i make hide div on outside click and at button next to vote bar while using this:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var votebox = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (votebox.style.maxWidth){
      votebox.style.maxWidth = null;
    } else {
      votebox.style.maxWidth = "160px";
    } 
  });
}
```

im making something like "staff votes" so basicly this code is best atm for me
heres whole code if ya would check it https://justpaste.it/49mfe

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var votebox = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (votebox.style.maxWidth) {
      votebox.style.maxWidth = null;
    } else {
      votebox.style.maxWidth = "160px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.okno {
  width: 70px;
  height: 60px;
}

.nick {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url[img/more.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 35px;
  -55px;
  50px;
  filter: opacity(.5);
  border: none;
}

.button:hover {
  filter: opacity(1];
}

.votebox {
  background: url[img/votebox.png] no-repeat;
  width: 160px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  70px;
  -50px;
  filter: opacity(.8);
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
}

.yesbar {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  8px;
  12px;
}

.nobar {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  8px;
  11px;
}

.yes {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  float: left
}

.no {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}

.voteyes {
  background: url[img/votego.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  140px;
  -50px;
}

.voteno {
  background: u rl(img/votegopng] no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  140px;
  -17px;
}
```

```html
<h3><img src="https://justpaste.it/img/head/staff.png" style="width:140px;height:70px;-15px;" /></h3>

<h4>Administrators</h4>
<div class="okno">
  <img src="">
  <div class="nick"></div>
  <button class="button" id="button"></button>
  <div class="votebox" id="votebox">
    <ul>
      <div class="yesbar">
        <div class="yes">
          <li style="font-size:16px;float:right;">70%</li>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nobar">
        <div class="no">
          <li style="font-size:16px;float:left;">30%</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <button class="voteyes"></button>
    <button class="voteno"></button>
  </div>
</div>

<h4>Senior Game Masters</h4>
<div class="okno">
  <img src="">
  <div class="nick"></div>
  <button class="button"></button>
  <div class="votebox">
    <ul>
      <div class="yesbar">
        <div class="yes">
          <li style="font-size:16px;float:right;">70%</li>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nobar">
        <div class="no">
          <li style="font-size:16px;float:left;">30%</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <button class="voteyes"></button>
    <button class="voteno"></button>

  </div>
</div>

<h4>Game Masters</h4>
<h4>Event Makers</h4>
<h4>Banners</h4>
<h4>Community Managers</h4>
<h4>Counsellors</h4>
<h4>Tutors</h4>
```

Comment: LI is a semantic child of UL or OL, not of DIV

Comment: `8px; 11px;` without a property is invalid CSS

Comment: `url[img/votego.png)` There's an invalid `[`

Comment: Avoid styling in JS, instead on click use `Element.classList.toggle("className", boolean)` and use a CSS className in your styles that will do the magic.